# Enhanced sidebar: question-related information

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The sidebar on WPSE is already providing a lot of helpful links and related questions. Nevertheless I would find it helpful to have some more *question-related* information (like the linked section).

Especially meta-information (check [summary of functions](http://queryposts.com/functions/) on QueryPosts for reference) like the implementation version of linked functions and related WordPress Core tickets might help people to get to the *source* of their problem more easily.

So I would like to discuss if it would be possible and useful to implement something like this:

[image: WPSE Sidebar Meta: Source and Linked Trac Tickets]

I could also think about some more information in the sidebar:

- [Link to source files](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0?order=name)
- [Link to class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference)
- Information based on question tags
- External links/resources (see [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress))

Comment: Instead of linking to the Codex, I'd like to see links to the new parsed Code Reference on developer.wordpress.org. It's essentially the official version of QueryPosts and will largely be replacing the function, hook, and class references currently residing in the Codex.